# Keep feeding class with information

Tags: java

I've developed a small game i want to make multiplayer.
I've made a gameserver, which keeps the client class updated with the current online players and positions.

Now i want to make the Client class feed the Game class with this information, so it's always up-to-date.

However, creating the Game class with a PlayerList parameter to the constructor will obviously not keep giving the up-to-date informations.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: perhaps this is more a question for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: write a thread which keep posting data

Comment: @G-Man : on what criteria do you say that? if a question contains the word _Game_ it does not mean its more suitable for gamedev.SE.com

Comment: @MukulGoel First of all I obviously tend to disagree. Secondly I don't apreciate you just flinging a friendly suggestion back into someone's face. Finally it is a state management issue which is inherent to games, therefore i still think gamedev will yield the best answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would actually use a [publish-subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) mechanism where the game server wouldn't maintain the list of players, but instead publishes the updates to the game domain objects. The players are subscribers or observers who will get notified whenever there is an update from the game server and refreshes the state of domain objects at their side.